# Fix weird NotAllowedError microphone error

Tags: javascript

one of the users reported me a weird issue :

in the remote debugging I've done, first the apps runs this function:

```
navigator.permissions.query({name: 'microphone'})
  .then(async (permission) => {

    alert(permission.state); // it returns prompt
    const success = await check(permission.state);

  }).catch(e => {

    resolve();

  });
```

The `permission.state` in the above code returns `prompt` Not denied, ok?

then the `check` function checks the mic permissions:

```
function check() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true
    }).then(stream => {
     
      resolve();
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err.name) //NotAllowedError
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

Here the `console.log(err.name)` returns the `NotAllowedError`

if the `navigator.permissions.query({name: 'microphone'})` returns `prompt` how the `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` returns the `NotAllowedError` it doesn't make sense to me ?

What is your suggestion ? How to fix this issue?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: "*query returns `prompt`, how getUserMedia returns `NotAllowedError` - it doesn't make sense to me?*" - sounds very much like the user was prompted and denied access.

Comment: no, if he/she denied access then query returns denied at the first point not prompt

Comment: Why would it have returned denied *before* the user was prompted?

Comment: query returns prompt because user not denied the permission yet, then without denying anything we get the `NotAllowedError` . that's the issue...

Comment: How do you know that it happened "*without denying anything*"? Calling `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` opens the prompt, and that can be denied.